# How to get dropdown list selected value in Label without using autopostback and update panel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to get dropdown list selected value in Label without autopostback and update panel in asp.net. i want the client side scripting for this code
i have the following code :-

```
protected void DropDownList1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
   // DropDownList1.Attributes["onclick"] =
   //"Label1.Text=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value";
}
```

Comment: try exploring jQuery! a bit of self-help! :)

Comment: Look at using Session Variable as well, or JavaScript

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use jquery (not everyone does! :) ) you can do it with standard javascript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function setLabelText() {
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("DropDownList1");
        document.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].text;
    }

</script>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" onchange="setLabelText();">
  <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="One" />
  <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Two" />
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: now this is pretty good. small snippet. no external javascript files and `ClientIDMode="Static"` good one...

Answer (score 2):

In your CS code, add an attribute such as:

```
ddlMyDrop.attributes.add("onchange","SetLabel(this,lblCtrl)");
```

In your JS code...

```
function SetLabel(sender, target){
    $(target).val($(sender).val());
}
```

This assumes you reference jQuery.

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery, why bother with setting the onchange in your CodeBehind?

Comment: That is a fair question. Attaching on codebehind was just an easy way to have everything automatically 'registered' when it goes out the wire so that the client doesn't have to attach on document ready or something like that. More of an ease of understanding than anything I guess.

Comment: was `document.getElementById("lblCtrl").innerHTML = sender.value` too little jQuery? :) +1 anyway...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this fairly easily with jQuery.  Label's turn into `span` and DropDownList into `select` on client side. Keep in mind that asp.net loves to append strings to the resultant content id's, *e.g.* MainContent_...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#MainContent_DropDownList1').change(function () {
        try {
            $('#MainContent_Label1').text($(this + "option:selected").text());
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using jQuery or Javascript as this is a fix of an existing site and it was not designed that way. Well I have gotten to a point where when the DropDownList is selected and does it's postBack I do my logic of setting the textBox readOnly status to true or false. the problem I have now is the the selectValue is not consistant. Wht it show in the selct field is not what is posted back to the page. Say I have None, 5.00, 10.00, 15.00, 20.00 as my choices to choose. I first choose 10.00 and it posts back None then I choose 20.00 it shows 10.00. It posts back the prior select value. the entire site is written from the code behind page. the aspx page is completely written from the .vb page. Everything is written into asp tags.  here is the code;

```
            If Page.IsPostBack Then
                If product_option_is_required > 0 then
                    myTextBox.ReadOnly= true
                Else
                    myTextBox.ReadOnly= false
                End if
                For Each child_control As Control In productOptions.Controls
                    If TypeOf child_control Is DropDownList Then
                        Dim child_ddl As DropDownList = child_control
                        tempName = products.getProductDependant("product_option_name",product_option_id)
                        tempSelectText = products.getProductSelectDependant("product_option_detail_name",child_ddl.SelectedValue)
                        priceDependant.Text ="here" & child_ddl.ID & " " & child_ddl.SelectedIndex & " " & child_ddl.SelectedValue & " --" & tempSelectText
                        If child_ddl.Text = "None" then
                            myTextBox.ReadOnly = true
                            myTextBox.Text = "If selected above enter name"
                        Else
                            myTextBox.ReadOnly = false
                            myTextBox.Text = ""
                        End if
                    End If

                next
            End if
```